# Erlang pinging between two different machines on same network

Tags: erlang

Trying to implement a erlang file server that transmits a file from raspberry pi to erlang server running on desktop. Am able to ping back and forth from raspberry pi and windows terminal. But when I ping from erlang shell of both the machines to each other, it just shows ‘pang’ and not ‘pong’. Have made sure that both machines are in same network. Moreover, pinging works on different instances of erlang shells in same machine, if I use net_adm:ping, but not to one another. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

You may have different cookies for the nodes. The default cookie is in your $HOME/.erlang.cookie (a random cookie file is created if this does not already exist), so all nodes started by the same user on the same machine gets the same default cookie. But if you run on different machines, the cookie files are probably different. Update them so they look the same, then try again.